# I am trying to call php functions from javascript using a post variable "action", but i cant seem to get a response from the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is sample code, so from my javascript i send a post variable called action = "login"

This action is sent to the controller.php file containing this

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){

        $action = $_POST['action'];
        $con = db_connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        switch($action){

                /****************************
                *           MISC SCENARIOS
                            **************************/

                        case "login":
                        login($con);
                        break;
            }

        mysqli_close($con); 
    }
?>
```

which then calls the login function that looks like this in the functions.php file

```
function login($con){

        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if(isset($email) && !empty($email) && isset($password) && !empty($password)){

            $connector = db_connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM edwaze_quiz.USERS WHERE EMAIL = '".$email."' AND PASSWORD = '".$password."' AND RIGHTS < 4;";

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($count == 1){

                $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                $name = $result['FIRST_NAME']." ".$result['SURNAME'];

                $path = '/quizz/profile images/';

                $picture = "unknown.jpeg";
                if($result['IMAGE'])
                    $picture = $result['IMAGE'];

                $picture = $path.$picture;

                echo json_encode(array($name, $picture));

            }else
                echo false;
            }
    }
```

Now, my issue is, this works perfectly in localhost. But when i put it on a remote server i get absolutely nothing back. NO response. I tried to put a bunch of "echo"s all over, even at the top after the "require_once" pieces of code in controller.php, still nothing.

config.php contains all the database variables requires e.g. username, password

I cant figure out why its not working, help please?

Comment: Try adding error_log to your php.ini and checking what the log says.

Comment: Database connection? Are you absolutely sure its working? That's the first thing to check if a code works on localhost and not on server...

Comment: @krozaine if the connection wasnt working, wouldn't the "echo" at the top of the controller.php file AT THE VERY LEAST be sent back??

Comment: @georg uhmm, unfortunate thing is I dont know where the php.ini file is. Direct me?

Comment: sure, `phpinfo()` will tell you

Comment: NOTE: this is a scaled down version of the actual files, there are alot more functions and cases in the switch statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down my problem to a line in a function that contained this

```
if(!empty(trim($fileName)))
    unlink($root."/".str_replace("../", "", trim($fileName)));
```

Turns out by removing the "trim" function from within the "empty()" to this

```
if(!empty($fileName))
    unlink($root."/".str_replace("../", "", trim($fileName)));
```

Solved the problem.

From the php manual for empty, this is quoted

> Note:
>   Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.
>   No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

I hope this helps someone. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This it ´s  a simple example :

```
<?php 


function login(){

        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        echo json_encode(array($email,$password));
}



if(empty($_GET["page"])) header("location:34975890.php?page=start");


if($_GET['page']=='start'){?>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JS -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getLogin(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '34975890.php?page=send',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {email: 'myemail@mail.com',password:'1234'},
                success:function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    alert("complete");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <form action="javascript:getLogin()">
        <button type="submit">Launch</button>
    </form>

<?php }else if($_GET['page']=='send'){

    login();

}

?>
```

Try it and  tell me , i only embebed html with php on a little example , but the data can be read. You can gently agregate part of your code to login php function.

Comment: okay, so i tried to remove all the code and put an "echo" and I got feedback!   So what do you think this means??

Comment: I think ive pin pointed the problem, when i put the echo after including the php file with the functions, theres a problem. Why do you think this happens?

Comment: i can see a mistake on the code .  }else
                echo false;
            }

try open tag of else like this 
}else{
                echo false;
            }

and close all structures

Comment: I've ran the code through syntax checkers, nothing has been found. The thing is this exact code was in a different file and it worked perfectly, now as functions alot of problems have come up.

Comment: Yes I mistaken with this. jejeje , i m going to replicate the situation on my computer . after I tell you something .